# Unable to run Facebook C# SDK samples

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I downloaded the latest Facebook C# SDK source along with samples. However when I run any of the sample I get this error:

> The web project XXX requires missing web components in order to load.
>   Would you like to download and install them using Web Platform
>   installer now?

No matter whether I click Yes or No the never loads. Can anybody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: @Neil Knight: Sorry. Here it is: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/72008/download/273075

Comment: @Neil Knight: Sorry. No I can't add reference either.

Comment: does it show what components are missing or what web installer is downloading?

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you unpack the zip the samples don't have the references to Facebook and Facebook.Web; you can run the **build.cmd** in the root of the samples to add these to each sample project automatically, or you can add them manually yourself.

Comment: Your solution looks promising but when I run I get 9 Warning(s) and 91 error(s) and on top of that I am still not able to open the samples. I ran build.cmd in "Run as administrator" mode in Windows 7